MacBook Pro 2017 speaker issue
On my MacBook Pro 2017 running macOS Monterey I see that coreaudiod is running in Activity Monitor, but there is no volume bar:


Is an output device selected? Can you select a different one, and if so, does the volume slider work? Have you tried quitting coreaudiod (it should restart automatically)?
